# I want to disable other buttons while my mouse is pointing to a button in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button

I want to disable other buttons while my mouse is pointing to another button in C#

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){    
   foreach (Button btn in Controls.OfType<Button>())
   {
    btn.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(btn_MouseEnter);
    btn.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(btn_MouseLeave );
   }
}
private void btn_MouseEnter(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
    var senderButton = (Button)sender;
    senderButton.Enable = true; // not working
}

private void btn_MouseLeave (object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
       var senderButton = (Button)sender;
       senderButton.Enable = false; // not working
}
```

Comment: So.. You want to disable all other button except the current hovering button?

Comment: Your code as posted is attempting to disable and re-enable the _current_ button, rather than the _other_ buttons.

Comment: your btn_MouseEnter event will trigger only when your button is enabled

Comment: Your question leaves me wondering why you want to do this... Surely if the mouse is over button x, you'll never have a chance to click elsewhere?

Comment: it's just only a test run to know if the methods if working.

Comment: @spender well, just for fun, please forgive me~ You can activate the button with keyboard, but I doubt anyone will do that (maybe prevent a cat jump on the keyboard?)

Comment: foreach... : btn.Enabled = btn==sender;

Answer (score 5):

This may not be the best solution, but i'll try anyways.

```
private void btn_MouseEnter(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
    var senderButton = (Button)sender;
    foreach(var btn in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {
        if (btn != senderButton)
            btn.Enabled = false;
    }
}

private void btn_MouseLeave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var btn in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {
        btn.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: As @uthistran-s comment, will the event fire when the button disabled?

Comment: @Alex Since the function to re-enable the buttons is fired by a button that is not disabled, it should do.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
senderButton.Enable = true;
```

you have to loop over all buttons like

```
foreach(Button btn in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    if (btn != senderButton)
        btn.Enable = false; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void btn_MouseEnter(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Button btn in Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            if (btn == ((Button)sender))
            {
                btn.Enabled = true; 
            }
            else
            {
                btn.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void btn_MouseLeave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Button btn in Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            btn.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```